# I want make conditional return in getcolor function leaflet js

Tags: javascript, leaflet, choropleth

Hello i want to make classification map, I try make conditional in getcolor function but it doesn't work and just appear with one color

This is my code

```
function openModal(e) {
  var t = e.target.feature.properties.url;
  $.getJSON("src/json/data-agregasi.json", function(e) {
    for (var a = e.length, o = 0; a > o; o++)
      e[o].url == t &&
        (dataStatistik(e[o]),
        $("#namaKecamatan").text("Demografi Kependudukan & Pendidikan di Kecamatan " + e[o].kecamatan),
        $("#luasWilayah").text(e[o].luas_wilayah),
        $("#kawasan").text(e[o].kawasan),
        $("#populasi").text(e[o].ikg, 0, "."),
        $("#jumlahKelurahan").text(e[o].jumlah_kelurahan),
        $("#jumlahSD").text(accounting.formatNumber(e[o].jml_sd, 0, ".")),
        $("#jumlahSMP").text(accounting.formatNumber(e[o].jml_smp, 0, ".")),
        $("#jumlahSMA").text(accounting.formatNumber(e[o].jml_sma, 0, ".")),
        $("#jumlahSMK").text(accounting.formatNumber(e[o].jml_smk, 0, ".")),
        $("#jumlahKeaksaraan").text(accounting.formatNumber(e[o].jml_keaksaraan, 0, ".")),
        $("#usiaSD").text(accounting.formatNumber(e[o].umur_7_12, 0, ".")),
        $("#usiaSMP").text(accounting.formatNumber(e[o].umur_13_15, 0, ".")),
        $("#usiaSMA").text(accounting.formatNumber(e[o].umur_16_18, 0, ".")),
        $("#jumlahPtkSD").text(accounting.formatNumber(e[o].jml_ptk_sd, 0, ".")),
        $("#jumlahPtkSMP").text(accounting.formatNumber(e[o].jml_ptk_smp, 0, ".")),
        $("#jumlahPtkSMA").text(accounting.formatNumber(e[o].jml_ptk_sma, 0, ".")),
        $("#jumlahPtkSMK").text(accounting.formatNumber(e[o].jml_ptk_smk, 0, ".")),
        $("#jumlahPtkKeaksaraan").text(accounting.formatNumber(e[o].jml_ptk_keaksaraan, 0, ".")),
        $("#jumlahPdSD").text(accounting.formatNumber(e[o].jml_pd_sd, 0, ".")),
        $("#jumlahPdSMP").text(accounting.formatNumber(e[o].jml_pd_smp, 0, ".")),
        $("#jumlahPdSMA").text(accounting.formatNumber(e[o].jml_pd_sma, 0, ".")),
        $("#jumlahPdSMK").text(accounting.formatNumber(e[o].jml_pd_smk, 0, ".")),
        $("#jumlahPdKeaksaraan").text(accounting.formatNumber(e[o].jml_pd_keaksaraan, 0, ".")));
  }),
    $("#statsModal").modal("show"),
    e.target.getBounds();
}

function getColor(e) {
  if (e > 20 && e.luas_wilayah < 6000) {
    return "#99000d";
  } else {
    return "#deebf7";
  }
}
```

Comment: please add `e`.

Answer (score 1):

You can not have a primitive value (without further implementing) and an object at the same time.

```
if (e > 20 && e.luas_wilayah < 6000) {
```

The easiest way, it to use a single number and check if the value is in the wanted range.

```
function getColor(e) {
    return e > 20 && e < 6000
        ? "#99000d"
        : "#deebf7"
}
```

Comment: but the variable which I want compare is different.

Comment: please add this variable to the question.